# [FromBody]JToken param is null when ContentType: application/json or it's bad serialized when Contenttype: application/x-www-form-urlencoded [Fiddler]

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

As the topic says, I've faced with a problem while trying to call an endpoint (POST) with a Request Body via Fiddler.

There is a http api method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("books")]
 public IHttpActionResult GetBooks([FromBody]JToken filterRequest)
 {...}
```

In Fiddler I make a POST call with request header:

`User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json`

And the Request Body looks like: `{ "title" : "Harry Potter"}`. While debugging it, I get null *filterRequest* parameter.

But when I use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, parameter *filterRequest parameter* is not null but unfortunately contains incorrect syntax like:

**{{"{ \"title\" : \"Harry Potter\"}": ""}}**

And it's wrong serialized by:

```
var columnsFilter = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(filter);
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. Maybe do you have met with similar problem and could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the whole problem was based on wrong **quotes**. I had to use just **`'`** and the posted request body was correct with `Content-Type: application/json.`